# CMake linking error (undefined reference to function)

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, g++

I'm working on C/C++ cross platform application. I'm using CMake for build process.

The project structure below is simplified, narrowing to the issue.

```
├── CMakeLists.txt 
├── Common_libs
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── File_Process_... (.cc/.h, 4 each)
└── MAIN
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── (Other subdirs and sources/headers)
```

**./CMakeLists.txt:(Common_libs)**

```
# CMakeLists.txt : CMake project, include source and define
# project specific logic here.
#

set(PKG_NAME File_Process)

add_library(${PKG_NAME} STATIC
    include/File_Process_Interface.h
    include/File_Process_Types.h
    include/FP_Directory.h
    include/FP_File.h
    include/FP_FileLP.h
    include/FP_Includes.h
    include/Filestruct.h
    ../../MAIN/error.h
    source/File_Process_Factory.cpp
    source/FP_Directory.cpp
    source/FP_File.cpp
    source/FP_FileLP.cpp)

target_include_directories(${PKG_NAME} PUBLIC include)
target_include_directories(${PKG_NAME} PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Common/Resources/3RD_PARTYLibrary/include)
    
if (WIN32)
    target_include_directories(${PKG_NAME} PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Common/Resources/Windows/Includes)
    install(TARGETS ${PKG_NAME} ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Common_libs/dist/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}/Win/)
else()
    SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11")
    install(TARGETS ${PKG_NAME} ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Common_libs/dist/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}/Linux/)
endif(WIN32)

target_include_directories(${PKG_NAME} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

**File_Process_Interface.h**

```
namespace AppExecutable{
    namespace Common {
        class File_Process_Factory {
        public:

            enum File_ProcessObjectType {
                FP_File, FP_Directory, FP_FileLP, Automatic_Detection
            };

        
            static IFile_Process* Create(File_ProcessObjectType type = FP_File, std::string source = "");
        };

    }
}
```

**File_Process_Factory.cpp**

```
namespace AppExecutable{
    namespace Common {

        IFile_Process* File_Process_Factory::Create(File_ProcessObjectType type, std::string source) {
            switch (type) {
            case File_Process_Factory::Automatic_Detection:
                struct stat st;

                if (stat(source.c_str(), &st) == -1) {
                    return NULL;
                }
                else {
                    if (S_ISDIR(st.st_mode)) {
                        return (IFile_Process*) (new Common::FP_Directory());
                    }
                    else {
                        if (source.rfind(".xyz") == (source.length() - 4)) {
                            return (IFile_Process*) (new Common::FP_FileLP());
                        }
                        else {
                            return (IFile_Process*) (new Common::FP_File());
                        }
                    }
                }
                //return (IFile_Process*)new Common::Automatic_Detection();
                break;
            case File_Process_Factory::FP_File:
                return (IFile_Process*) (new Common::FP_File());
                break;
            case File_Process_Factory::FP_Directory:
                return (IFile_Process*) (new Common::FP_Directory());
                break;
            case File_Process_Factory::FP_FileList:
                return (IFile_Process*) (new  Common::FP_FileLP());
                break;
            default:
                throw ("Unknown File_ProcessObjectType");
            }
        }
```

**./CMakeLists.txt:(MAIN)**

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)
project(AppExecutable C CXX)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0015 NEW)

    if (WIN32)
        include_directories(MAIN
                            MAIN/shared)
        link_directories(../Common_libs/dist/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}/Win/)
    else()
        include_directories(MAIN
                            MAIN/shared)
endif(WIN32)

file(GLOB SOURCES
    *.cpp
    shared/*.cpp
    shared/*.c)
# Add source to this project's executable.
if (WIN32)
    add_executable (AppExecutable ${SOURCES})
    install(TARGETS AppExecutable DESTINATION  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Application/Windows/)
    target_link_libraries(AppExecutable File_Process)
else()
    add_executable (AppExecutable ${SOURCES})
    install(TARGETS AppExecutable DESTINATION  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Application/Linux/)
    target_link_libraries(AppExecutable File_Process)
endif(WIN32)

SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(AppExecutable PROPERTIES  DEBUG_POSTFIX "_debug")
```

Finally, when I do make, the following error is generated:

```
[ 33%] Built target Common_libs
[ 38%] Linking CXX executable AppExecutable 
CMakeFiles/AppExecutable.dir/MAIN/FileEntry.cpp.o: In function `AppExecutable::Common::FileEntry::FileSimulation(int, char**)':
FileEntry.cpp:(.text+0xaa9): undefined reference to `AppExecutable::Common::File_Process_Factory::Create(AppExecutable::Common::File_Process_Factory::File_ProcessObjectType, std::string)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [AppExecutable/AppExecutable] Error 1
make[1]: *** [AppExecutable/CMakeFiles/AppExecutable.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

**link.txt**

```
/opt/gcc54/bin/g++  -std=c++11 -O3 -DNDEBUG  -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ CMakeFiles/AppExecutable.dir/Output_App.cpp.o CMakeFiles/AppExecutable.dir/FileEntry.cpp.o CMakeFiles/AppExecutable.dir/AppExecutable.cpp.o CMakeFiles/AppExecutable.dir/ABCBaseClass.cpp.o CMakeFiles/AppExecutable.dir/ABCControl.cpp.o CMakeFiles/AppExecutable.dir/shared/CsvReader.c.o CMakeFiles/AppExecutable.dir/shared/OutputInterface.cpp.o CMakeFiles/AppExecutable.dir/shared/DataBlock.cpp.o CMakeFiles/AppExecutable.dir/shared/lElement.cpp.o CMakeFiles/AppExecutable.dir/shared/lParser.cpp.o CMakeFiles/AppExecutable.dir/shared/lParserCApi.cpp.o CMakeFiles/AppExecutable.dir/shared/ssupport.cpp.o CMakeFiles/AppExecutable.dir/shared/lVersionParser.c.o  -o AppExecutable  ../Common_libs/libFile_Process.a
```

I'm able to generate executable in Windows, I'm having issue on linux.
I've been trying to fix this for some time. Why it is showing errors if it has already been built before the linkage?

Comment: So the most obvious explanation is that you haven't defined `AppExecutable::Common::File_Process_Factory::Create(AppExecutable::Common::File_Process_Factory::Common_libsObjectType, std::string)`. Are you sure that you have? Can you provide some evidence this is the case (like the source code). This maybe be completely obvious to you, but we do see posts where people are complaining about linker errors when all that is wrong is that they've failed to define the symbols the linker is complaining about.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: `file(GLOB...` is bad. Hides things from you

Comment: @john I've added source to the question, I've defined it. I'm able to build exe in windows and I'm having issues in linking it Linux build

Comment: @CodeDevil I guess the next thing would be to get a print of the linker command that your build is executing.

Comment: @john I've added content from link.txt

Comment: Are the cases of your filename extensions correct? If not glob won't pick them up (a good reason not to use glob). I can't see `File_Process_Factory.cpp` in your compiler command

Comment: @AlanBirtles `File_Process_Factory.cpp` is in CMakeLists.txt of `File_Process` static library.

Comment: Maybe add `SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11")` to your application build? We still need a [mre] really

Comment: Your code shows the definition of the function signature `Create(AppExecutable::Common::File_Process_Factory::File_ProcessObjectType, std::string)`, with the first argument to `Create` being `File_ProcessObjectType`. Do you make an alias for this somewhere? Because the linker is complaining it cannot find `Create(AppExecutable::Common::File_Process_Factory::Common_libsObjectType, std::string)`. Note, here the first argument is `Common_libsObjectType` instead. You still have not shown the code where this is defined...

Comment: @squareskittles `Common_libsObjectType` is defined in File_Process_Interface.h

Comment: Can you then show this definition? As I commented earlier, the `Create` function declaration shown in `File_Process_Interface.h` does **not** match the function signature the linker is looking for. The linker is looking for a function signature `Create(Common_libsObjectType, std::string)`, not `Create(File_ProcessObjectType, std::string)`...

Comment: Thanks for editing, but something still doesn't add up. Can you perhaps show the contents of FileEntry.cpp, particularly the instance where you try to use the `Create` function?